# Does the extension to the pro-completion of a left exact (finite) colimit preserving functor preserve (finite) colimits

Tags: ct.category-theory

Let $\mathbf C$ be a category with finite limits.  Then a left exact functor $F\colon \mathbf C\to \mathbf{Set}$ is pro-representable and hence extends to the pro-completion $\mathbf C$.  My question is whether it is true that the extension of $F$ preserves finite colimits whenever $F$ does, and if so what is a reference?  I'm also curious about arbitrary colimits but for the application I care about, finite colimits (or even coequalizers) are enough.

Comment: what do you mean here by the extension of $F$ to $pro(C)$ the pro-completion of $C$?? $\mathbf{Set}$ has cofiltered limits, so _any_ functor $G \colon C \to \mathbf{Set}$ extends to the pro-completion (this is a free completion) regardless of $F$ being left exact or not.

Comment: Under my assumptions F is representable on pro(C).  I want to know whether this representable functor on pro(C) preserves finite colimits if F did on C.

Comment: Ok, I see what you mean; just a little clarification: by "this representable functor on $pro(C)$" you mean 1. $pro(C)(-,F)\colon pro(C)^{op} \to \mathbf{Set}$ or 2. $pro(C)(F,-)\colon pro(C) \to \mathbf{Set}$??

Comment: The covariant representable, i.e., option 2.  

Answer (score 2):

I am not certain if he provides the answer to your question, but Dan Isaksen's paper:
Calculating limits and colimits in pro-categories, Fundamenta Mathematicae 175 (2002) 175--194. 
is relevant I think. The point is that the reindexing lemmas in procategories provide a powerful tool for calculating limits and colimits.

Comment: No guarantees but it  makes some good points.  Reindexing lemmas are very important in pro-category theory in order to prove structural lifting results.